# How can I make different captures of a wildcard compatible?

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to make a generic class with one type parameter, `class MyClass<E>`, that has a class variable of a second generic class with two type parameters, `SecondClass<V, E>`. Since for my code it really doesn't matter what the type of `V` is, I declare the type of that variable as `SecondClass<?, E> var`. At some point in the implementation of MyClass I call a method on var that returns a V, `public V foo(E e)`, and then I pass this object of type V to another method of var, `public int bar(V v)`. However, this doesn't compile because of reasons I only vaguely understand, but I believe it is explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557316).

Apparently, the capture-of-? returned by foo is different from the the capture-of-? required by bar. But why? Whatever the actual type of V is, it *must* be the same for both methods, since they are invoked on the same instance. What am I missing here?

Ultimately, what I would like to know is this: what do I need to change in order to make the code compile, without adding V to the type parameters of MyClass? (I don't want to enforce users of MyClass to specify the type of V since it shouldn't matter)

---

To give you a more concrete example, here's a simplified version of what I'm working on. As you may already have guessed by the type parameters, it concerns graphs. `MyClass` translates to `EdgePainter` and `SecondClass` translates to `Graph`. With this code, the compile error is in the first line of `EdgePainter.getColor(E)`.

```
class Graph<V, E>
{

    public V getTarget(E edge)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public int getInDegree(V vertex)
    {
        return 0;
    }

}

class EdgePainter<E>
{

    private static final Color COLOR_FOR_MANY_EDGES = Color.RED;
    private static final Color COLOR_FOR_FEW_EDGES = Color.BLUE;

    private Graph<?, E> graph;

    public EdgePainter(Graph<?, E> aGraph)
    {
        graph = aGraph;
    }

    public Color getColor(E edge)
    {
        // My compiler says:
        // The method getInDegree(capture#3-of ?) in the type
        // Graph<capture#3-of ?,E> is not applicable for the arguments
        // (capture#4-of ?)
        int degree = graph.getInDegree(graph.getTarget(edge));
        if (degree > 10)
            return COLOR_FOR_MANY_EDGES;
        else
            return COLOR_FOR_FEW_EDGES;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why can't you just add V as a type of EdgePainter?

Comment: As Ben Schulz pointed out nicely: I need a type argument for the implementation, but want to hide it from API users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture the wildcard by invoking a generic method.

```
public Color getColor(E edge) {
    return getColorInternal(graph, edge);
}
private <X> Color getColorInternal(Graph<X, E> g, E e) {
    int degree = g.getInDegree(g.getTarget(e));
    // ...
}
```

This is a typical scenario. You need a type argument for the implementation, but want to hide it from API users. If many methods are affected it can be helpful to define a separate, perhaps nested, class `EdgePainterInternal`. This internal implementation has the second type parameter `G` and the publicly visible implementation `EdgePainter` delegates *all* calls to an instance of `EdgePainterInternal`.